# background image svg sa data:image not displayed

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg as a background image and I would like to be able to update the color as I want, so I created an scss mixin

```
@mixin backgroundTick($color) {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><path fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#{$color}" stroke-width="2" d="M.688 6.299l4.5 3.6L11 2"/></svg>');
}
```

For example the result can me

```
data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><path fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" d="M.688 6.299l4.5 3.6L11 2"/></svg>
```

But nothing is displayed, see this example https://jsfiddle.net/96emhq4v/

But if I am creating a svg file containing

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><path fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" d="M.688 6.299l4.5 3.6L11 2"/></svg>
```

There is no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your SVG first then used as a background-image

This is your SVG code i just filled black color

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><path fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" d="M.688 6.299l4.5 3.6L11 2"/></svg>
```

This is encoded version of your SVG you can easily encoded from here [URL-encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)

```
%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='13' height='13' viewBox='0 0 13 13'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23000000' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke='%23000' stroke-width='2' d='M.688 6.299l4.5 3.6L11 2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

Now you can used as a background-image

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='13' height='13' viewBox='0 0 13 13'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23000000' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke='%23000' stroke-width='2' d='M.688 6.299l4.5 3.6L11 2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using background images. Instead you can add your SVG and make it absolte positioned to the div you wanted it to make it's background. It should take the same dimensions if you put left,top,right,bottom to 0. Adjust the z-index and give  elements a class, with css fill, stroke you can then change the color. Won't work if your importing it as an image. Cool thing is that svgs are very good scalable and won't have pixel issues.